# Android: Using dimen.xml from code

Tags: android, dimensions

I am using dimen.xml for supporting multiple screen sizes.

How can I access the file and get the dimen from code so can be used in the application?

Yoav

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
float yourDimen = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.your_dimen_name);
```

Answer (score 3):

yes just create different values folder with different qualifiers like res/values-320x480/ , you can  use as  mention in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) and [link2](http://droiddevelop.tumblr.com/post/9993651158/part-93-using-a-dimension-xml-file-with-different)

```
Resources res = getResources();
float fontSize = res.getDimension(R.dimen.font_size);
```